# Replacement of tf.contrib.learn.run_n in tensorflow 1.0+

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow 1.1.0 to run a code that is written with prior versions of tensorflow. It includes this part:

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=64, state_is_tuple=True)

outputs, last_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    cell=cell,
    dtype=tf.float64,
    sequence_length=X_lengths,
    inputs=X)

result = tf.contrib.learn.run_n(
    {"outputs": outputs, "last_states": last_states},
    n=1,
    feed_dict=None)
```

I get the following warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/graph_actions.py:900: run_feeds_iter (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.graph_actions) is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-02-15.
Instructions for updating:
graph_actions.py will be deleted. Use tf.train.* utilities instead. You can use learn/estimators/estimator.py as an example.
```

I couldn't find the replacement of `tf.contrib.learn.run_n` in tensroflow 1.0+. Is there an alternative function that I can use instead?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether there is one function that can directly substitute the function in question. The following alternative should work without warnings:

```
n_iter = 1
result = []
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(n_iter):
        result_ = sess.run({'outputs': outputs, 'last_states':last_states}, feed_dict=None)
        result.append(result_)
```