# tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell creates variable shape mismatch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to understand RNN cell wrapper in TensorFlow (version 1.3) with the following code (taken from [here](https://github.com/dennybritz/tf-rnn/blob/master/rnn_cell_wrappers.py.ipynb)).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.reset_default_graph()
X = np.random.randn(2, 10, 8)

X[1, 6:] = 0
X_lengths = [10, 6]

cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=64, state_is_tuple=True)  
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell=cell, output_keep_prob=0.5)

# cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells=[cell] * n, state_is_tuple=True)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells=[cell for _ in range(n)], state_is_tuple=True)

outputs, last_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    cell=cell,
    dtype=tf.float64,
    sequence_length=X_lengths,
    inputs=X)
result = tf.contrib.learn.run_n(
    {"outputs": outputs, "last_states": last_states},
    n=1,
    feed_dict=None)
print(result[0]["outputs"].shape)
print(result[0]["outputs"])
...
```

The first question is related to the line of code that involves `tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell`. Specifically, the code runs fine when `n=1` (meaning only one layer is actually generated). When `n>=2` is used, there is always a error message as following (both the commented original line and another implementation below it suggested [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7604) give the same error information):

> ValueError: Trying to share variable
>   rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/kernel, but specified shape (128,
>   256) and found shape (72, 256).

Based on my investigation so far, the error comes at the `tf.nn_dynamic_rnn()` function call. But I could not figure out the exact reason yet. 
Could someone please explain it and also give some guideline on how to use the RNN cell wrappers?

The second question is related to a WARNING message on deprecation of `tf.contrib.learn.run_n` function. The message also suggest the following:
Use `tf.train.*` utilities instead. You can use learn/estimators/estimator.py as an example.
I also could not find out a good way to use the right utilities here (forgive my shallow knowledge on TensorFlow).
Any comments/suggestions on either or both questions are most welcomed.
Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend that you ask your second question separately. Stack O likes to keep each question pretty atomic. I believe the first question has been answered (the fix works on my system anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did some search and found that [CentAu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418495/replacement-of-tf-contrib-learn-run-n-in-tensorflow-1-0) asked the same question before but has not received an answer yet. To not duplicate the question, maybe you can shed some light there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your array of cells differently as of maybe version 1.1. I am guessing the code you are working from was written before that. Use something like:

```
cells = []
for _ in range(n)
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=64, state_is_tuple=True)  
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell=cell, output_keep_prob=0.5)
    cells.append(cell)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells, state_is_tuple=True)
```

The problem is that the syntax you have currently tries to reuse the same `cell` object `n` times, so you run in to some issues with sharing variables. If you do it the way I suggest, you define each `cell` uniquely and avoid accidentally sharing variables.

Comment: Thanks Engineero, your suggestion is right. Variable sharing is the problem. Do you happen to know the solution for the second question? (I realized that you probably is typing the answer while I am editing the second question).